# Версия vs appsettings.json

Tags: javascript, c#, visual-studio, mongodb

> Объясните, пожалуйста, какая версия vs используется на картинке, спрашиваю тк у меня нет файла appsettings.json.

[image]

Comment: [Как задать хороший вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Судя по жёлтому флажку в верхнем правом углу, это vs 2017